# Problem create tigger for autoincrement on phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, database-trigger

I would like to make a trigger after delete that take the value max ID + 1 for my autoincrement.

Here is my current code with the error from MySQL:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER form_id_autoincrement
AFTER DELETE ON tbl_form
IF EXISTS (SELECT `form_id` FROM tbl_form) 
    THEN
        ALTER TABLE tbl_form AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(`form_id`)+1 FROM tbl_form);
ELSE
    ALTER TABLE tbl_form AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
END IF;
END; //

DELIMITER;
```

`` #1064 - Error syntax near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT `form_id` FROM tbl_form) 
    THEN
        ALTER TABLE tbl_f' line 3 ``

Comment: I doubt that this is a problem with phpMyAdmin. You should tag it with the database you use e,g, MySQL or MariaDB

Comment: The trigger cannot use statements that explicitly or implicitly begin or end a transaction - that is ALTER is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE` is not allowed inside trigger in Mysql.

So If you are using MySQL & you want to alter table on any `Delete` in table `tbl_form`, then you may able to do that only from your server side code, like you can make one function and call it after delete is done successfully.